# Series of inverse zeros of bessel functions

Tags: bessel-functions

I am interested in the numerical values for the series  $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{j_{0,n}^4}$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{l=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{1}{j_{l,m}^4}$. where  $j_{k,m}$ is the $m-th$ positive zero of the Bessel function of order $k$. Are there known formulas for other exponents (rather than $4$)?

Comment: Searching, I found this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.0228.pdf

Comment: This one too  https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/C534430ADB75F2A796EB66C0C78B7AE3/S2040618500034067a.pdf/on_some_infinite_series_involving_the_zeros_of_bessel_functions_of_the_first_kind.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot. DeLyras paper gives me what exactly I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From 'Spectral Sum Rules for the Circular Aharonov-Bohm Quantum Billiard,' F. Steiner, Fortshcr. Phys. 35 1, p 87-114 (1987).  The history of this problem is much older than this reference.

A table is given of the closed forms of the following, for $s=1,2,...10$. I'll stop a short list at s=4.
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (j_{a,k})^{-2s}$$
$$s=1: \quad  \frac{1}{4(a+1)}$$
$$s=2: \quad \frac{1}{16(a+1)^2(a+2)}$$
$$s=3: \quad \frac{1}{32(a+1)^3(a+2)(a+3)}$$
$$s=4: \quad \frac{5a+11}{256(a+1)^4(a+2)^2(a+3)(a+4)} $$

Answer (score 1):

I do not know any formula for the computation of
$$S_k=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(j_{0,n}\right){}^{-k}$$ but we can compute them to high accuracy (even if it takes a quite long time).

For $k=4$, the result, for twenty five significant figures is $0.03125000000000000$ and the number of trailing $0$'s is quite impressive (notice that, for $k=2$, the result is $0.25000000000000000$ ). I suppose that this hides something I totally ignore.

I suppose that this hides something I totally ignore. I tried (with no success at all) to use some of the approximations of the zeros.

Answer (score 1):

For $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\nu\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0,-1,-2,\dotsc\}$, the sequence $$\zeta_{\nu}(2k)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{j_{\nu,n}^{2k}}$$ can be determinantally represented as
\begin{equation}\label{zeta=bessel-det-eq}
\zeta_{\nu}(2k)
=\frac{(-1)^{k+1}\nu}{(2k)!}
\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{1}{(\nu)_0} & \frac{1}{(\nu+1)_0} & 0 &\dotsm & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{(\nu+1)_0} &\dotsm& 0 & 0\\
\frac{1}{2(\nu)_1} & \frac{1}{2(\nu+1)_1} & 0 &\dotsm & 0 &0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
\frac{(2k-3)!!}{2^{k-1}(\nu)_{k-1}} & \frac{(2k-3)!!}{2^{k-1}(\nu+1)_{k-1}} & 0 & \dotsm & \frac{1}{(\nu+1)_0} & 0\\
0 & 0 & \binom{2k-1}{1}\frac{(2k-3)!!}{2^{k-1}(\nu+1)_{k-1}} & \dotsm & 0 & \frac{1}{(\nu+1)_0}\\
\frac{(2k-1)!!}{2^{k}(\nu)_k} & \frac{(2k-1)!!}{2^{k}(\nu+1)_k} & 0 & \dotsm & \binom{2k}{2k-2}\frac{1}{2(\nu+1)_1} & 0
\end{vmatrix}.
\end{equation}

Y. Hong, B.-N. Guo, and F. Qi, *Determinantal expressions and recursive relations for the Bessel zeta function and for a sequence originating from a series expansion of the power of modified Bessel function of the first kind*, CMES Comput. Model. Eng. Sci. **129** (2021), no. 1, 409--423; available online at https://doi.org/10.32604/cmes.2021.016431.

Comment: See also the paper: Yue-Wu Li, Feng Qi, and Wei-Shih Du, Two forms for Maclaurin power series expansion of logarithmic expression involving tangent function, Symmetry, vol. 15 (2023), no. 9, Article 1686, 18 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.3390/sym15091686.

Answer (score 0):

This Rayleigh sums can be calculated using a recurrence formulas, see papers:

[1] Kishore, The Rayleigh function, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 14 (1963), 527-533.

[2] Sneddon I. N., On some infinite series involving the zeros of Bessel functions of the first kind, Glasgow Mathematical Journal , Volume 4 , Issue 3 , January 1960 , pp. 144 – 156

[3] Elizalde, E., Leseduarte, S., & Romeo, A. (1993). Sum rules for zeros of Bessel functions and an application to spherical Aharonov-Bohm quantum bags. Journal of Physics A: Mathematical and General, 26(10), 2409–2419. doi:10.1088/0305-4470/26/10/012

[4] J.L. deLyra, On the sums of inverse even powers of zeros of regular Bessel functions, arXiv:1305.0228 [math-ph]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi Kamil. Are you willing to include these formulas in your post, here on stackexchange? That would make your post much more useful.

Comment: I wish to , but I am not familiar with Latex :( and writing by hand this simple formula makes me too large problems - is it any calculator online to generate the latex codes?