# Evaluating $\int_0^{\pi/2} \log(1 - x \cot x) \, dx\;$ (Is there a closed form?)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I am interested in knowing if it is possible to find a closed-form solution to the following challenging log-cotangent integral

> $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \log(1 - x \cot x) \, dx$$

I very much doubt a closed form in terms of known mathematical constants can be found and have no reason to suspect one exists.

In the absence of a simple closed-form value being found, maybe the integral can be evaluated in terms of an infinite series. In this direction, since $0 < x \cot x < 1$ for all $x \in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ the log term appearing in the integrand can be expanded. Doing so produces
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \log(1 - x \cot x) \, dx = -\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (x \cot x)^n \, dx = -\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n},$$
where
$$a_n = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (x \cot x)^n \, dx. \tag1$$
Noting that
\begin{align*}
a_1 &= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x \cot x \, dx = \frac{\pi}{2} \log (2)\\
a_2 &= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (x \cot x)^2 \, dx = \pi \log (2) - \frac{\pi^3}{24}\\
a_3 &= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (x \cot x)^3 \, dx = \frac{9\pi}{16} \zeta (3) - \frac{\pi^3}{16} + \frac{3\pi}{2} \log (2) - \frac{\pi^3}{8} \log (2),
\end{align*}
perhaps it is possible to find a general expression for $a_n$. Indeed, an attempt at finding (1) can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2721739/closed-form-for-the-integral-int-0-pi-2-fracx-sin-x-tan-x-x-dx/2764887#2764887).

Any other approaches or suggestions to this challenging integral would be welcome.

Comment: Noting that the integrand is $0$ at $0$ and $\frac\pi 2$, it is possible you could convert it to a complex integral of a meromorphic function about a closed curve, or possibly the real part of such an integral. Then you could use the Residue theorem to evaluate it.

Comment: Inversion formula for bernoulli polynomials might be useful here as I had seen its use in evaluating $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x^{n}cot(x) dx$

$$x^n=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{j=0}^{n} \begin{pmatrix}
    {n+1} \\
    j 
    \end{pmatrix}
   B_{j}(x)$$

Comment: The formula you reference is really confusing to code as it involves the analytically continued $\eta$ -function and relies on $0^0$ being defined as 1. $\eta(1)=\log 2$ so your statement above is incorrect. There is a typo in the formula which does help matters $2^l$  should be  $2^{n-l}$. The sum that runs to $n-1$ can run to $n$.

Comment: The same integral was discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3515040/348034).

Comment: @James Arathoon - Ah yes, $\eta (1) = \log (2)$, my error.

Comment: @Paul Enta - Indeed it is. In all my searching I seemed to have missed this. From the discussion there it would seem there is no closed-form expression after all.

Comment: As long as we do not know the general formula for the $a_n$, we shall be stuck. Moreover, the convergence would be extremely slow.Summing $100 k$ terms at the time would give $$\{3.04764,3.13672,3.17634,3.20000,3.21616,3.22809,\cdots\}$$

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Edited to make the answer self-contained

We introduce first a representation of the integral which makes use of Bessel functions:
\begin{align}
 I&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \log(1 - x \cot x) \, dx\\
 &=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \log\left( \frac{\sin x-x\cos x}{\sin x} \right) \, dx\\
 &=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \log\left( \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{x^{3/2}J_{3/2}(x)}{\sin x} \right) \, dx\\
 &=-\frac{3\pi}{4}+\pi\ln \pi-\frac{\pi}{4}\ln 2-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln 2 -\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\log\left( J_{3/2}(x) \right)\,dx
\end{align}

In a paper by [Dickinson](https://www.ams.org/proc/1954-005-06/S0002-9939-1954-0086897-8/S0002-9939-1954-0086897-8.pdf) a series expansion is given for the derivative of the logarithm of a Bessel function:
\begin{equation}
 \frac{d}{dx}\log J_\nu(x)=\frac{\nu}{x}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2x^{2k+1}}{j_{\nu,n}^{2k+2}}
\end{equation}
$j_{\nu,n}$ is the $n$-th zero of the Bessel function of order $\nu$. This result holds provided $0<x<j_{\nu,1}$ (which is the case here). By integrating this result,
\begin{equation}
 \log J_\nu(x)=\nu\log(x)-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k+1}\frac{x^{2k+2}}{j_{\nu,n}^{2k+2}}+C
\end{equation}
The constant is determined by adjusting the result for $x\to0$. As $\log J_\nu(x)= \nu\log x-\nu\log 2-\log\Gamma(\nu+1)+O(x^2)$
\begin{equation}
 C=-\nu\log 2-\log\Gamma(\nu+1)
\end{equation}
Then,
\begin{equation}
 \log\left(J_{3/2}(x) \right)=\frac{3}{2}\log x-\frac{3}{2}\log 2-\log\left(\frac{3\sqrt{\pi}}{4}\right)-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2k+2}}{k+1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{j_{3/2,n}^{2k+2}}
\end{equation}
The integral reads thus
\begin{equation}
 I=\frac{\pi}{2}\left( 3\ln\pi-3-\ln(12) \right)-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(\pi/2)^{2k+3}}{(k+1)(2k+3)}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{j_{3/2,n}^{2k+2}}
\end{equation}
The sum of inverse even powers of zeros of Bessel functions appears in problems involving the diffusion equation and a broad literature exists on the topic. The quantity
\begin{equation}
 \sigma(p,\nu)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{j_{\nu,n}^{2p}}
\end{equation}
is discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2911997/348034). A recent analysis can be found in a paper by [Jorge L. deLyra](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.0228.pdf).
The first values for $\nu=3/2$ are
\begin{align}
 &\sigma(1,3/2)=\frac{1}{10}\;;\;\sigma(2,3/2)=\frac{1}{350}\;;\;\sigma(3,3/2)=\frac{1}{7875}\\
 &\sigma(4,3/2)=\frac{37}{6063750}\;;\;\sigma(5,3/2)=\frac{59}{197071875}
\end{align}
we find
\begin{align}
 I&=\frac{\pi}{2}\left( 3\ln\pi-3-\ln(12) \right)-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\sigma(k+1,3/2)}{(k+1)(2k+3)}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2k+3}\\
 &=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(3\ln\frac{\pi}{e}-\ln(12) \right)-\\
&\hspace{1cm}-\frac{\pi^3}{8}\left(\frac{1}{30}+\frac{(\pi/2)^2}{3500}+ \frac{(\pi/2)^4}{165375}+\frac{37(\pi/2)^6}{218295000}+\frac{59(\pi/2)^8}{10838953125}+\cdots \right)
\end{align}
which is identical to the series proposed by @ClaudeLeibovici.

As remarked by @JamesArathoon in a comment, it is also possible to perform first IBP on the integral. Then, the problem boils down to integrate $J_{1/2}(x)/J_{3/2}(x)$. By using the recurrence formula of the Bessel function, it requires to integrate $J_{5/2}(x)/J_{3/2}(x)$. A series expansion for the ratio of consecutive Bessel functions is also given in the above cited paper. It also makes use of the $\sigma(k,3/2)$, but the convergence is slower in this case.

Comment: Very nice to make a link with Bessel functions.

Comment: It's also worth noting that a very similar sequence of coefficients arises when the integral is split instead as follows $$-\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \log (\cos (x)) \, dx-\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \frac{x^2 \sin (x)}{\sin (x)-x \cos (x)} \, dx$$

Comment: Yes, that was my first idea, but the series, corresponding to the integral of $J_{1/2}/J_{3/2}$ or $J_{5/2}/J_{3/2}$ are slightly less quickly convergent.

Answer (score 9):

*Just based on approximations.*

First of all, a Taylor expansion
$$\log (1-x \cot (x))=2\log(x)-\log(3)+\frac 13\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {a_n}{5^n\,b_n} x^{2n}$$ where the first $a_n$'s are
$$\{1,13,22,907,55282,298183,738788,11537791247,\cdots\}$$ the first $b_n$'s are
$$\{1,42,189,19404,2837835,35756721,202621419,7114443263928,\cdots\}$$  makes the series to converge very fast. Truncating and using $p$ terms give the following numerical results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p &  I_p\\
 1 & -3.362471345 \\
 2 & -3.354577981 \\
 3 & -3.353531646 \\
 4 & -3.353370377 \\
 5 & -3.353343240 \\
 6 & -3.353338390 \\
 7 & -3.353337483 \\
 8 & -3.353337307 \\
 9 & -3.353337272 \\
 10 & -3.353337265
\end{array}
\right)$$
Another,almost equivalent, possibility  could be to use the $[2p,4]$ Padé approximant of the integrand and use partial fraction decomposition

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & I_p \\
 1 & -3.353356609 \\
 2 & -3.353338184 \\
 3 & -3.353337337 \\
 4 & -3.353337269 \\
 5 & -3.353337263
\end{array}
\right)$$

Just for the fun of it, the result is "close" to
$$-\frac{1}{10} \zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \left(\frac{1}{2}-\Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{24}\right)\right)$$ which is in a relative error of $5.75 \times 10^{-7}$%.

**Edit**

In a comment, @James Arathoon suggested to work instead
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \left(\log \left(\frac{x^3}{3}\right)-\log (\cos (x))\right) \, dx+\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \log \left(-\frac{3 (x \cos (x)-\sin (x))}{x^3}\right) \, dx$$

The first integral does not make any problem
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \left(\log \left(\frac{x^3}{3}\right)-\log (\cos (x))\right) \, dx=-\frac{\pi}{2}   (3+\log (12)-3 \log (\pi ))$$

The second integrand can write
$$\log \left(-\frac{3 (x \cos (x)-\sin (x))}{x^3}\right)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {c_n}{5^n\,d_n} x^{2n}$$ where the first $c_n$'s are
$$\{1,1,1,37,59,2753,1654,\cdots\}$$ and the first $d_n$'s are
$$\{2,28,189,38808,315315,71513442,202621419,\cdots\}$$ and the convergence is quite fast.
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \log(1 - x \cot (x)) \, dx=
-\frac{\pi}{2}   (3+\log (12)-3 \log (\pi ))-$$ $$\frac{\pi ^3}{240}\Bigg[1+\frac{3 \pi ^2}{1400}+\frac{\pi ^4}{88200}+\frac{37 \pi ^6}{465696000}+\frac{59 \pi ^8}{92492400000}+\cdots \Bigg]$$ Using the above terms leads to an absolute error equal to $7.39 \times 10^{-8}$.

Using the $[8,4]$ Padé approximant and partial fraction decomposition leads to an absolute error equal to $5.72 \times 10^{-11}$.

**Update**

Using the same approach as @River Li
$$I = \int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \log(1 - x\cot (x))\,dx
= - \frac{\pi^3}{24} + \frac{\pi}{2}\log( 2) - \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x^3}{\tan (x) - x} \,dx$$ we can easily build the $[2p,4]$ Padé approximant of the left integrand which write
$$\frac{x^3}{\tan (x) - x} =\frac {3+\sum_{k=1}^p a_k\,x^{2k} } {1+b_1 x^2+b_2 x^4 }$$ the integration of which leading to a polynomial of degree $(2p-1)$ plus two hyperbolic arctangents.

As a function of $p$ the result of this integration is given below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 &  \color{red}{3.150202}313227377435283622 \\
 3 &  \color{red}{3.15020211}4234142271205176 \\
 4 &  \color{red}{3.1502021130}45512153905225 \\
 5 &  \color{red}{3.15020211302}9044077891702 \\
 6 &  \color{red}{3.15020211302878}5049324311 \\
 7 &  \color{red}{3.150202113028780}655331848 \\
 8 &  \color{red}{3.15020211302878057}7184507 \\
 9 &  \color{red}{3.1502021130287805757}51197 \\
 10 & \color{red}{3.15020211302878057572}4358 \\
 11 & \color{red}{3.1502021130287805757238}48 \\
 12 & \color{red}{3.150202113028780575723839} 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Converges slightly faster if you split the integral as follows $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \left(\log \left(\frac{x^3}{3}\right)-\log (\cos (x))\right) \, dx+\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \log \left(-\frac{3 (x \cos (x)-\sin (x))}{x^3}\right) \, dx$$ and study the Taylor series of the second integral

Comment: @JamesArathoon. This is good idea I shall try tomorrow morning (curfew time here). Thanks & cheers :-)

Comment: @JamesArathoon. This was an incredibely good idea. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

*I prefer to add another set of comments.*

Suppose that we use
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \log(1 - x \cot (x)) \, dx = -\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (x \cot (x))^n \, dx = -\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n}$$ where
$$a_n = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (x \cot (x))^n \, dx$$ It seems possible to compute the $a_n$'s for any value of $n$. I have not been able to find, even emprically, any relation between them.

Now, let us consider
$$b_k=\sum_{n = 1}^k \frac{a_n}{n}$$  The problem is that the convergence is extremely slow
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & b_k &  {b_k}/{b_{k-1}} \\
 1 & 1.088793044 &  \\
 2 & 1.531621992 & 1.406715445 \\
 3 & 1.787024517 & 1.166752976 \\
 4 & 1.958303531 & 1.095845923 \\
 5 & 2.083382818 & 1.063871246 \\
 6 & 2.179888546 & 1.046321649 \\
 7 & 2.257271880 & 1.035498757 \\
 8 & 2.321115965 & 1.028283738 \\
 9 & 2.374959149 & 1.023197111 \\
 10 & 2.421167052 & 1.019456294 \\
 20 & 2.680973995 & 1.006279984 \\
 30 & 2.800600958 & 1.003289782 \\
 40 & 2.873001074 & 1.002089208 \\
 50 & 2.922816842 & 1.001472276 \\
 60 & 2.959780104 & 1.001107498 \\
 70 & 2.988610619 & 1.000871248 \\
 80 & 3.011910979 & 1.000708125 \\
 90 & 3.031249532 & 1.000590014 \\
 100 & 3.047635130 & 1.000501298
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

**Approximating the integral using rational approximants**

Using integration by parts, we easily get
$$I = \int_0^{\pi/2} \ln(1 - x\cot x) \mathrm{d} x
= - \frac{\pi^3}{24} + \frac{\pi}{2}\ln 2 - \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x^3}{\tan x - x} \mathrm{d} x.$$
$I \approx -3.353337262889472...$

We focus on
$$I_1 = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x^3}{\tan x - x} \mathrm{d} x.$$
We may approximate $I_1$ by rational approximants to $\tan x$ at $0$.

1. Pade $(5, 4)$ approximant $\tan x \approx \frac{x(x^4 - 105x^2 + 945)}{15x^4 - 420x^2 + 945}
   \triangleq g(x)$

We can bound the error by
$$0 \le \frac{x^3}{g(x) - x} - \frac{x^3}{\tan x - x} \le g(\pi/2) \approx 0.000045.$$
We have
$$I_1 \approx \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x^3}{g(x) - x} \mathrm{d} x = 
- \frac{5}{112}\pi^3 + \frac{165}{56}\pi - \frac{243}{56}\sqrt{10} 
\operatorname{arctanh} \frac{\pi\sqrt{10}}{30}.$$
Then we have $I \approx -3.353344689$ with relative error $< 0.000003$.

Answer (score 2):

This is a **long comment** on an intriguing approximation to the integral most easily accessible by CAS calculation.

Taking the integral partition

$$I=-\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \log (\cos (x)) \, dx-\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \frac{x^2 \sin (x)}{\sin (x)-x \cos (x)} \, dx$$

we work with the second integral.

First note that $\frac{d }{dx}(\sin (x)-x \cos (x))=x \sin (x)$. Using the substitution $y=(\sin (x)-x \cos (x))$ we are left to compute the inverse trigonometric function $x= arc[\sin x-x\cos x](y)$, since $dy=x \sin x \,dx$ and $y=(\sin (x)-x \cos (x))$ is a one-to-one function between $0$ and $\pi/2$.

(I write $x= arc[\sin x-x\cos x](y)$ for want of better terminology).

Therefore

$$I=-\int_0^1 \frac{arc[\sin x-x\cos x](y)}{y} \,dy$$

Using CAS to determine $arc[\sin x-x\cos x](y)$ in series form, we have

$$arc[\sin x-x\cos x](y)=\sqrt[3]{3} \sqrt[3]{y}+\frac{y}{10}+\frac{41 y^{5/3}}{1400 \sqrt[3]{3}}+\frac{97 y^{7/3}}{8400\ 3^{2/3}}+\frac{15063 y^3}{8624000}+\frac{6199421 y^{11/3}}{7207200000 \sqrt[3]{3}}+\frac{1894073471 y^{13/3}}{4237833600000\ 3^{2/3}}+\frac{1532283399 y^5}{19059040000000}+\frac{11288018107137217 y^{17/3}}{252957982717440000000 \sqrt[3]{3}}+\frac{1496852049518257 y^{19/3}}{59133034920960000000\ 3^{2/3}}+\frac{31831777776715674057 y^7}{6536309355896320000000000}+...$$

with the general term of the term by term integral being

$$-a_n\int_0^1 \frac{y^{(2n-1)/3}}{y} \,dy=-\frac{3\, a_n}{2n-1}$$

and with the general form of the resulting approximate sum being

$$I\approx a+3^{-1/3}b+3^{-2/3}c$$

where $a,b,c$ are rational, with $a\approx-0.10059903$, $b\approx-3.0016854$ and $c\approx-0.0059380965$

Obviously in the summation limit as $n \to \infty$ $a,b$ and $c$ may no longer be rational.